# Pooled likelihood in R, how to code it?

Tags: r

I don't really know how to construct the following likelihood in R.

I have panel data for several individuals. Each individual is observed over time and I have several observations for each individual. I assume that the observations for each individual are independent and follow a normal distribution with an individual-specific mean and a variance common to all the individuals. In other words, I want to use all the data for estimating the variance, while using individual specific data to estimate the individual means.

Formally, let $i=(1,2,...,N)$ be the $i-th$ individual and $j=(1,2,...,n_i)$ the $j-th$ observation of individual $i$.

The likelihood function for individual $i$ is

$$
L_i(\mu_i,\sigma)=\prod_{j=1}^{n_i}\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp(-\frac{(x_{ij}-\mu_i)^2}{2\sigma^2})
$$

```
L_i(mu_i, sigma) = PRODUCT_j 1/(sigma*sqrt 2pi) * exp( -(x_ij-mu_i)^2/2sigma^2 )
```

and the full likelihood is then

$$
L(\mu_1,...\mu_N,\sigma)=\prod_{i=1}^N \prod_{j=1}^{n_i}\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp(-\frac{(x_{ij}-\mu_i)^2}{2\sigma^2})
$$

```
L_i(mu_i,...,mu_N, sigma) = PRODUCT_i L_i(mu_i, sigma)
```

What's a smart way to code the log of the full likelihood in R in order to pass it to some optimizer?

Example data:

```
set.seed(2)

A  <- rep(1,15)
B  <- rep(2,11)
ID <- c(A,B)

dA <- rnorm(15,2,3)
dB <- rnorm(11,1,3)
X  <- c(dA,dB)

DATA <- data.frame(ID,X)
DATA
```

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot use nlme or lme4 packages, which will do this for you?

Comment: If you are only asking for code, this question is off-topic for CV. We will try to migrate it for you.

Comment: Thank you. I wasn' sure whether it was more appropriate here or somewhere else (StackOverflow?). As for the use of existing packages, I would like to know how to construct it myself as I will have to expand it in the near future.

Comment: If you must code it yourself, you might want to consider working with the log-likelihood.